# next() and prev() with find

Tags: jquery, html

I have a markup which is the following:

```
<div>
  <a href="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img1.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="img2.jpg">
    <img style="display: none" src="img2.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="img3.jpg">
    <img style="display: none" src="img3.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="img4.jpg">
    <img style="display: none" src="img4.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="img5.jpg">
    <img style="display: none" src="img5.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="img6.jpg">
    <img style="display: none" src="img6.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

as you can see the first image inside the first `<a>` is shown. I would like to trigger a function that the next `<img>` gets shown and the first invisible.

```
var visible = $('img:visible');
$('#trigger').click(function() {
   visible.next('a').find('img').fadeIn();
   visible.fadeOut();
});
```

how do I have to handle `.find()` and `next()` that it will work?

Comment: The images have no next element in line. Target the `parent()` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting the visible image element.as a is not the sibling of image, `visible.next('a')` will return undefined. You need to traverse to parent anchor(using `.closest('a')` or `.parent()`) and then use `.next()`.Try this:

```
 visible.closest('a').next().find('img').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
visible.parent().next('a').find('img').fadeIn();
```

since you want to get the next immediate sibling of parent anchor of visible image instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
visible.closest('a').next('a').find('img').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

update this:

```
var visible = $('img:visible');
```

to this:

```
var visible = $('img:visible').closest('a');
```

---

Because with your existing selector `visible` is trying to find another anchor next to itself, which is not there so that won't work instead you can update your `var visible` to the traverse up to the closest parent, which is anchor an `a`.